# is there a way of adding form control to the input fields on woocommerce in wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I'm trying to style the form input fields to make it look nicer. Anyone know how this is easily done?

I've looked round to see in the php files but no luck on where to change this.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `woocommerce_form_field_<type>` filter to control the output of Woocommerce input elements.

```
//replace <type> with the type of input you need to update
function filter_woocommerce_form_field_<type>( $field, $key, $args, $value ) { 
    //edit or override the field here...
    return $field; 
}; 
         
add_filter('woocommerce_form_field_<type>', 'filter_woocommerce_form_field_type', 10, 4);
```

Reference: http://hookr.io/filters/woocommerce_form_field_type/

Comment: So is this to be put into the functions.php file or in the files i want it to change?

Comment: @LEWC It can be put in the functions.php file or a plugin. I would recommend researching [Wordpress filters and actions](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API#Hooks.2C_Actions_and_Filters) if you are unfamiliar with the workflow.